# Iterating over all squarefree composites < L

Tags: java, loops, recursion, optimization, time-complexity

I need to iterate over all integers that are:

1. Composite
2. Squarefree
3. Smaller than a limit L

And see for each one if it has a certain property (in addition to these 3). I then need to sum all such integers with this property. The following code does exactly that:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    long L=(long) Math.pow(10,12);
    long [] primes = eratosthenes(L/2);
    long sigma=0;
    for (int i=0;i<primes.length-1;i++)
        sigma+=squareFreeCompositesGenerator(L,primes[i],i+1,primes);
    System.out.println(sigma);
}

public static long squareFreeCompositesGenerator(long L, long prod, int position, long [] primes)
{
    long sum=0;
    for (int i=position;i<primes.length&&prod*primes[i]<=L;i++)
    {
        if (property(prod*primes[i]))
            sum+=prod*primes[i];
        sum+=squareFreeCompositesGenerator(limit,prod*primes[i],i+1,primes);
    }
    return sum;
}
```

The idea behind this, is that rather than checking all numbers up to `L` if they're squarefree, I can rather simply create them, which is considerably faster. In this code, a call for `eratosthenes(n)` returns a sieve of all primes up to `n`. The method squareFreeCompositesGenerator then "creates" all squarefree composites smaller than `L`, and checks if they have the property through the `property` method. Through recursion, it keeps multiplying the primes without repetition and runs through all possible combinations. The "Achilles" heel of this algorithm though, is in the very beginning, where I require all primes `p⩽L/2`. This is due to the fact that the largest possible such integer can be of the form `2⋅p` where `p` is the largest prime up to `L/2`. The program runs swiftly even for `L=10^9` but for `L` as big as `10^12`, I can't create and store all those primes in reasonable time.

It is important to note I don't need to sum all squarefree composites `< L`, or count how many there are, but rather iterate through all of them and check if they have a certain property.

Is there any way to adjust the code so that it only requires primes up to `√n (n^1/2)`? Is there perhaps another approach to iterate through all squarefree composites `< L` with a sublinear time complexity?

Comment: Methinks you learned a bit since last talking about this ;-)

Comment: haha, just trying to do the best :) @GhostCat

Comment: Have you checked [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/316376/how-to-calculate-these-totient-summation-sums-efficiently)

Comment: @juvian No, can you explain how this is related please?

Comment: It´s related to your other question. Assumed it had to do with this one. If not, would help if you add what is the property you are checking, because I don´t think what you are doing can be done in better complexity than O(sieve + amount of squarefree composites).

Comment: I'm looking for numbers such that `n-phi(n)` perfectly divides `n-1`. One way to look at it boils down to the question above. @juvian

Comment: Is this calculation equivalent to the other? Because the other already has a O(n^2/3) solution and this one won´t be less than O(n)

Comment: Nono, this question and my previous one are different. They are related to different matters. @juvian

Comment: Is your current problem the memory of the sieve or the time it takes?

Comment: Even if I had infinite memory, generating all primes up to `L/2` would take quite some time. I assume about a day or so. I can live with that, but I can't store the 3 billion primes below the limit (the real limit is a little lower). Given this is not feasible, and I take memory out of the question, I will say time is the real problem here. The current time complexity is too high for that limit. An optimization to this algorithm is needed, or a different one altogether - with a lower complexity. @juvian

Comment: Unless you figure out some property about the numbers that satisfy your property, even iterating all square free composites would take a lot of time. Only related thing I found was [this](http://www.hdml.gr/pdfs/journals/544.pdf) and considering it leaves as an open question whether there are infinite numbers that satisfy your property, it does not seem to be easy. As for memory, you could just iterate all numbers and calculate phi and if its a square free number in O(sqrt n) and end up with a O(n sqrt n) approach with no memory usage. Using memory up to sqrt(n) would speed up these functions.